# Can't use startapp in virtualenv

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenv

I keep on getting an import error message when trying to use the command django-admin.y startapp . The thing is that the problem only occurs when I am in my virtualenv. The error message is:

```
  File "/Users/Opare/.virtualenvs/p2_dev/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/Users/Opare/.virtualenvs/p2_dev/lib/python3.4/site-     packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in       execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Opare/.virtualenvs/p2_dev/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/Opare/.virtualenvs/p2_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/Opare/.virtualenvs/p2_dev/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/Opare/.virtualenvs/p2_dev/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Users/Opare/.virtualenvs/p2_dev/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'p2'
```

install app settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'movements',
'users')
```

Comment: Can you show your INSTALLED_APPS setting? It looks like that may be where this is originating.

Comment: I'd guess you forgot to install something on your virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

Have you used p2 module in your program?
Maybe there's a difference in your real python environment and the virtualenv python.
I'd guess you forgot to install the p2_dev package in the virtualenv.
Maybe there's another package dependencies missing when you fix the p2_dev.

So, for safe, I have a advice, you can start a virtualenv with(in windows):

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages virtualenv_project
```

And then, you will get the same packages in your virtualenv with the real python.